# Highlight several element with single mousover/hover event. Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, hover

Is there any chance with `mouseover` (or any other) event on certain element to get following html

**e.g.** highlight all previous cells:

**start:** `class="selected"`,

**finish:** cell with onmouseover event

```
#if mouse pointer is on the cell #4
<li id="1" class="reg"></li>
<li id="2" class="selected"></li>
<li id="3" class="in_range"></li>
<li id="4" class="in_range"></li>
<li id="5" class="reg"></li>
<li id="6" class="reg"></li>
<li id="7" class="reg"></li>
<li id="8" class="reg"></li>
<li id="9" class="reg"></li>
<li id="10" class="reg"></li>

#if mouse pointer is on the cell #6
<li id="1" class="reg"></li>
<li id="2" class="selected"></li>
<li id="3" class="in_range"></li>
<li id="4" class="in_range"></li>
<li id="5" class="in_range"></li>
<li id="6" class="in_range"></li>
<li id="7" class="reg"></li>
<li id="8" class="reg"></li>
<li id="9" class="reg"></li>
<li id="10" class="reg"></li>


#if mouse pointer is on the cell #8
<li id="1" class="reg"></li>
<li id="2" class="selected"></li>
<li id="3" class="in_range"></li>
<li id="4" class="in_range"></li>
<li id="5" class="in_range"></li>
<li id="6" class="in_range"></li>
<li id="7" class="in_range"></li>
<li id="8" class="in_range"></li>
<li id="9" class="reg"></li>
<li id="10" class="reg"></li>
```

Comment: Many things, it's about the second day since I'm trying to solve this. Now I'm trying to play with pseudo css classes, maybe some css tricks can solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said to target all Previous Elements...

```
$("li").hover(function(){
    $(this).prevAll().not(":first").addClass("in_range");
});
```

**UPDATE**

**[WORKING FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hemal_301080/ytm6bLkt/11/)**

Use `.prevUntil()` to find out previous siblings until you reach first one. For that you have to change class name of first `<li>` as i have done in UPDATED FIDDLE.

```
$("li").hover(function(){
    $(this).prevUntil(".not").addClass("in_range");
});
```

Comment: The solution will include ALL previous elements, while I need to highlight all previous elements excluding elements below <li id="2" class="selected">. E.g. I don't want to highlight <li id="1"> Any ideas how to limit it?

Comment: I'll try to play with .prevUntil()

Comment: Please see the updated code. I have excluded first `<li>`

Comment: Hemal, you're great!

Comment: You cannot have elements with identical id's at the same page, you can move them to a `class` attribute instead.

Comment: @AlexF Please accept as answer if it solved your problem

Comment: Btw, Hemal, since you are an expert, is there any chance to have kind of hover effect? When I have mouse pointer over cell #6, all previous cells are highlighted with red but when I move mouse pointer to cell #4, cell #5 and cell #6 have their original style back?